# how Login session maintained in scrapy

Tags: scrapy

I have a simple login and another page behind the login. Once I complete the login (I can get user session). If I request another page the session is gone

The sample implementation

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
class TestSpider(Spider):
   name = "test"
   allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
   start_urls = ["https://example.com/customer/account/login/"]

   def parse(self, response):
     token =                 response.xpath(".//input[contains(@name,'token')]/@value").extract()[0]

     yield FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formnumber=1,
        formxpath=".//*[@id='form-account-login']",
        formdata={
                'token' : token,
            'LoginForm[email]': 'xxxx',
            'LoginForm[password]': 'xxxx',
        },
        clickdata={'id': 'customer-account-login'},
        callback=self.parse1,
        )

   def parse1(self, response):
     return scrapy.Request(url="https://example.com/customer/account/list/", callback = self.parse_2, errback=self.error)

   def parse1(self,response):
     open_in_browser(response)
```

Comment: `COOKIES_DEBUG=True` can help spot problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you've got

```
COOKIES_ENABLED = True
```

in your `settings.py` file

UPD:
You define `parse1` method twice in your code.

```
   def parse1(self, response):
     return scrapy.Request(url="https://example.com/customer/account/list/", callback = self.parse_2, errback=self.error)

   def parse1(self,response):
     open_in_browser(response)
```

Comment: i added that line also still i'm not getting